# search for a string using javascript and redirect the page if result is true

Tags: javascript

I need to find a string from the body and if result is true - redirect to another page.

I've tried something like this ..

```
var str = document.documentElement.innerHTML;
var re = 'someWord';
if (str.search(re) = -1)
{
    location.replace("http://google.com");
}
```

but it doesn't work.

I am  new to javascript, so i need your help. Thanks in advance !!

Comment: try `str.search(re) == -1`

Comment: This is a typo, it should be `==` and not `=` , `=` is assignment. Also, in fact you're looking fof `!=` because `-1` means it's _not_ there.

Comment: thx 4 your help? but im still dont understand.. function theSearch (){
  var str = document.documentElement.innerHTML;
  var re = 'notranslate123';
  if (str.search(re) !== -1){
   location.replace("http://google.com");
  }
 } redirects allways

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use indexOf function of javascript:

Case sensitive:

```
if (str.indexOf("someWord") >= 0)
```

Case insensitive:

```
if (str.toLowerCase().indexOf("someword") >= 0)
```

Answer (score 2):

You should read your error message. Given that code, you should be seeing this error:

```
ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment
```

So it looks like you are doing an invalid assignment, perhaps here?

```
if (str.search(re) = -1){
```

Yeah, you probably meant an equality check instead:

```
if (str.search(re) == -1){
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try this

```
var str = document.documentElement.innerHTML;
var re = 'someWord';
if (str.search(re) == -1){
     location.replace("http://google.com");
}
```